# How to add windows media player context menu to library root folder

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-media-player, context-menu

How can I add windows media player options to my music library root folder's context menu?
I have VLC player and MP3tag installed which DO have options on context menu but windows media player is missing.

The folder is already optimised for music in properties->customize which sub-folder option checked and the media player options DO appear on individual artist subfolders.

My end goal is to be able to right click my music folder and "Play with windows media player" every file in every sub-folder.

[image: Music context menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to specifically add the WMP options to the `My Music` folder, but I did find a way to add the options to *all* folders, including `My Music`. To do so, copy/paste the following into Notepad, save it as `WMPDirectory.reg`, double click this file to add it to the registry, and reboot:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00
"NeverDefault"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Play]
@="&Play with Windows Media Player"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,31,00,00,00
"NeverDefault"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Play\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{ed1d0fdf-4414-470a-a56d-cfb68623fc58}"
```